# SQL Server 2008 Inserting new record for missing dates in a table

Tags: sql, sql-server

I have two sql tables 
Table1 Columns: Product, Enddate (eg: 2014-01-31 00:00:00.000 ), saleAmt
Table2 has only one column: EndDate (eg: 2014-01-31 00:00:00.000 )

The first table has TotalMonthly sales amount for each Product for the last 12 months. 
Issue: Some Products do not have any sales for a month and so the data is not displayed for that product for that month. I want the missing months to display with a sale amount of 0

This is how the data looks in Table1 now:

```
**Product   EndDate   SaleAmt**
TireMC  12/31/2013     5600
TireMC  1/31/2014      800
TireMC  2/28/2014      2400
TireMC  7/31/2014      1600
TireMC  10/31/2014     4600
TireMC  11/30/2014     4200
```

I want to compare this table1 Date with Table2 Date and get the missing Dates from Table2 into Table1 for each Product in Table1 and leave the SalesAmt as null for these.

```
**Product   EndDate        SaleAmt**
TireMC  12/31/2013         5600
TireMC  1/31/2014            800
TireMC  2/28/2014            2400
TireMC  3/31/2014            0
TireMC  4/30/2014            0
TireMC  5/31/2014            0
TireMC  6/30/2014            0
TireMC  7/31/2014            1600
TireMC  8/31/2014            0
TireMC  9/30/2014            0
TireMC  10/31/2014           4600
TireMC  11/30/2014           4200
```

How can I accomplish this.

Thanks for the help in advance.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If I understand your question correctly, you're looking for the `cartesian product` of all dates in your second table with all products in your first table.  You can use a `cross join` to create that.  Then you need to use an `outer join` to get the results for the sames amt, using `coalesce` to convert null values to 0:

```
select t1.product, t2.enddate, coalesce(t3.saleamt,0) saleamt
from (select distinct product
      from table1) t1
cross join (select distinct enddate
            from table2) t2
left join table1 t3 on t1.product = t3.product 
  and t2.enddate = t3.enddate
```

- [SQL Fiddle Demo](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!3/3db54/5)

Comment: This selection gives me the desired result but How do I put just the missing date records for each product back in Table1?

Comment: @svon - just use `insert into ... select ...` and add a null check -- this should do it: http://sqlfiddle.com/#!3/64202/1